# How to return value from anonymous function nested in javascript (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm having problems trying to add rows to the variable x. I have not understood how to return a value from an anonymous function called by another function.

```
var pgClient = new pg.Client(connectionString);
pgClient.connect();
var query = pgClient.query("SELECT * from sceglie");

var x = [];

query.on("row", function(row,result){
    result.addRow(row);
    x.push(row);
});

console.log(x);
```

Comment: you... don't. it's that simple.

Comment: @KevinB but is there a solution to create a generic function like function foo (query_string,DB_URL){} that returns the result of the query on this DB?

Comment: The anonymous function will run asynchronously (everytime the "row" event occurs) and `console.log` will execute right away, so at that time `x` will always be empty. You'll need some sort of callback.

Comment: No, it simply is not possible to have a function that returns the result of an asynchronous action unless the asynchronous action was already complete before said function was called.

Comment: Another relevant canonical dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @JohnnyHK I don't think this is an exact duplicate as the question is not specifically about asynchronous JavaScript, but about retrieving the result of an PostgreSQL query.

Comment: @Duncan It actually is the same because the results of a PostgreSQL query are delivered asynchronously; so the `on` callback is async.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I've found that `client.query('SELECT * from sceglie', [], function (err, result) {})` will execute the query synchronously. So that could be an answer to this question, instead of some information about async JS.

Comment: @Duncan I don't mean to difficult, but the callback to `client.query` is also async. async callbacks for DB operations is a fundamental concept in node.js.

Comment: @JohnnyHK That's true, but that way he can use the full result of the query at once, which is what I think his goal was here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you are trying to do.  Javascript is a synchronous language in that it executes line by line.   So this line:

```
console.log(x)
```

Will execute right away.  The "on" function will only execute when it is called, so your log statement will always have the empty value.

[Link to good article explaining JS environment](https://simpleprogrammer.com/2016/06/06/javascript-execution-stack-key-learning-language/)